# how to add a custom field in the "Add New page" page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, hook

I'm developing a wordpress plugin that would show page specific content in the sidebaer, and I want to specify the content in the **"create new page"** page.

for example, if I create a page named "ERP product", I may specify some custom HTML markup, that may include a youtube video, a download link, or even just some text. So, if I navigate to the page "ERP product", only then I get to see the specified content in the sidebar widget, other pages may have different values or pages without value may have a different value. I'll find a workaround with the widget part, but I need help with adding the textarea to specify the page specific contents in the "new page" page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you want I believe:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box

This will allow you to add sidebar boxes to the post/page editor and save the values entered there as custom fields.